# How to extract data from dictionary in the list

Tags: python, list, extract

I'd like to obtain the data of dictionary in the list as follows.

```
list=[{"length": {"a": 0.05,"b": 0.04}, "id": "66"}]
```

How should I extract {"a": 0.05,"b": 0.04} and "66" from this list?

Comment: What language is this? Python, JavaScript? You don't have a list, you have a dictionary (or object) inside a list (or array). This should be covered in any Python tutorial, just check the manual for lists. You access an item using `myList[1]` where `1` here is the order of the item in the list.

Comment: I'm sorry, what specific programming language are you using? Or are you asking for a generalized programming concept? It is good to provide a minimal code example of what you have attempted that illustrates what problem you have encountered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I use python, so I want to know the code of python.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems here:

1) You define a variable named `list`, which would clash with the keyword `list`.  That will lead to confusing results if you later try to create a `list` using the keyword.

2) You stored a single dictionary inside of a list.  Why not just create a dictionary, like this:

```
dictionary = {"length": {"a": 0.05,"b": 0.04}, "id": "66"}
```

And then you could get the data that you want with the following commands:

```
dictionary["length"]  # Gets {"a": 0.05,"b": 0.04}
dictionary["id"]      # Gets "66"
```

However, since you currently have this within a list, the answer to you question is to first get element 0 from the list, and then apply the previous commands.  This would look like the following:

```
list[0]["length"]  # Gets {"a": 0.05,"b": 0.04}
list[0]["id"]      # Gets "66"
```

Comment: I don' define the list, I extract the json_data from web site.
But the problem is solved.
Thank you so much

Comment: Glad I could help.  Please don't forget to mark this as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
list=[{"length": {"a": 0.05,"b": 0.04}, "id": "66"}]

for ele in list:
    for key, value in ele.items():
       print(value)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 0.05, 'b': 0.04}
66
```

Explanation:

As you are using `list`, first iterate over the list :

```
for ele in list:
```

Then iterate over the `dictionary` using `.items`:

```
for key, value in ele.items():
```

Then print the values:

```
print(value)
```

This will be your required output

Answer (score 0):

You can use pull values from a dict like this too

```
ls=[{"length": {"a": 0.05,"b": 0.04}, "id": "66"}]

ls[0].values()

dvas = [ds.values() for ds in ls]

dvas = [*map(dict.values, ls)]
```

you should also try to avoid using built in names(list) for your variable name assignment, you can avoid a lot of bugs with this practice